# How to access semaphore data from another program

Tags: c, semaphore

I am trying to understand how to use Semaphores for my current class I am taking. The assignment is supposed to use a script that runs 4 programs, one after another. program 0 is always executed first. From here, any of the programs can be started in any particular order following the program 0. Although, they can be executed in any order. Only the execution of program 0 to program 1, to program 2, and then to program 3 should output.

I am needing to use system V semaphore (semget, semop, semctl).
The professor also mentions that I should use errno command to help develop this code.

I need to create the semaphore within program 0, then each other program should run in the previously specified order dependant on the value of the semaphore.

My question is, how do I create the semaphores and then access the data from the semaphores for all the other programs that want to access them.

Comment: Have you read the man pages or other documentation for those functions?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I just don't really understand how they are supposed to be used to achieve this purpose. I have at least read the man pages anyway. trying to get some more information, but haven't really found anything helpful.

Comment: W. Richard Stevens' book Unix Network Programming Vol. 2 is a good resource.

Comment: Okay, thank you. ill take a look at this.

Comment: Use a 'named' semaphore.  Each program needs to connect to the 'named' semaphore.